# salesforce Chatter Integration with iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, salesforce

I am quite new to iOS and am trying to integrate salesforce chatter feature i my native ios App.I've been trying to do this for long time but havent had any success.It'll be really helpful if someone can guide mr on this or point to some good tutorial.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the iOS [Sample Project](https://github.com/cseymourSF/Chatter-API-iOS-Sample). This should be an efficient entry point.
Everything else about the `Chatter API` is linked on [this page](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Chatter_API).

Answer (score 0):

You will get the pdf of the tutorial from [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Samples/blob/master/iOS/tutorials/NativeiOSTutorial/NativeiOSTutorial.pdf?raw=true). And also see the [SalesforceNativeSDK Reference](http://forcedotcom.github.io/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/Documentation/SalesforceNativeSDK/html/index.html). And you will have the sdk [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS). Hope these links will help you.

Comment: Hey can you pls help me out With some code or good tutorial. The link for github that you sent is laso not working. I am unable to run that App coz when i clone it restkit.xcodeproject is missing and when i download restkit and added it to project many errors came. Pls help me out on this.